# How do get docker working after software installation?

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a docker machine based on openSUSE with Apache2, MySQL Server and pure-ftpd. After I installed the software, stopped the docker container and ran it again with binding port 80 to 80 and port 21 to 21 this time, it seems that I am not able exec any command. It always hangs. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container is already binding to ports 80 and 21. You need to either restart the container with `docker restart` or destroy it with `docker rm` and create a new container.

Comment: no, but there are failures with systemd. That isn´t supported in docker as a red hat developer said.